# Error in matching values in second third place of array-list in my login function?

Tags: java, user-interface, arraylist

I have a home assignment in which i have to make a log in register form using joptionpane and taking inputs only using arrayList, its a basic task but I'm stuck here,"I made a function to match values in a array-list but it displays wrong output".

I have tried using different loops and using different placements for the input values but i didnt get the desired result.

```
public class register {
    ArrayList regUser;

    register()
    {
        this.regUser=new ArrayList();
    }

     public void regUser(){
            String regName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter User Name:");
            String regPass = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter User Password:");

            userData p = new userData(regName,regPass);

            regUser.add(p);
        }
public void login()
    {
        String name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter User Name:");
        String password = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter User Password:");

        for(int i=0; i<regUser.size(); i++)
        {
            userData k = (userData)regUser.get(i);
            if(name.equals(k.name) && password.equals(k.password)){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Welcome to Rent A Car\n All cars data here....");

            }
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Wrong login info please try again");

        }
```

I am accepting that my login method checks each entire in arraylist for the input value of login user and if there is no entire matching only then displays an error.
But my programs works fine for first arraylist values, but doesnt work for next values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class UserData {
  private final String username;
  private final String password;

  UserData(String username, String password) {
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
  }

  public String getUsername() {
    return username;
  }

  public String getPassword() {
    return password;
  }
}

class Registration {
  private final List<UserData> userData = new ArrayList<>();

  public void regUser() {
    String regName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter User Name:");
    String regPass = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter User Password:");
    userData.add(new UserData(regName, regPass));
  }

  public void login() {
    String name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter User Name:");
    String password = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter User Password:");

    boolean isValidUser = userData.stream()
        .anyMatch(user -> user.getUsername().equals(name) && user.getPassword().equals(password));

    if (isValidUser) {
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Welcome to Rent A Car\n All cars data here....");
    } else {
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Wrong login info please try again");
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem apart from the bad quality of your code is the following:

you have a name say "name1" and a password say "pass1" 
and you check if it is equal to each of the registered users.
 you probably want to use the contains() method of the List interface 
 so if the username and the password are in the list then write a success message, else fail.